# How to fix expected integer Error when increment array with a string in Tcl

Tags: tcl

This is a Tcl code that tries to add item to an array inside namespace

```
namespace eval catalog {
    variable entries
    array set entries {}

    proc add {item} {
        variable entries
        incr entries ($item)
    }
    proc getEntries {} {
        variable entries
        return [lsort [array names entries]]
    }
    proc countInstances {item} {
        variable entries
        return $entries($item)
    }
}

catalog::add apple
```

When I add using catalog::add apple and run the script this is an error what I got :

```
expected integer but got "(1)"
    (reading increment)
    invoked from within
"incr entries ($item)"
    (procedure "catalog::add" line 3)
    invoked from within
"catalog::add 1"
    (file "procex.tcl" line 19)
```

and the question is of course how can I fix it, what did I wrong

Comment: There is an addtional space character in `incr entries ($item)` It should be `incr entries($item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as the error says. `(1)` is not an integer but a string.

```
incr entries ($item)
```

tries to increment the variable `entries` by `($item)`.

From the other parts of the code, it is obvious that `entries` is an array, so `entries` itself cannot be incremented, from which I conclude that you actually meant to do:

```
incr entries($item)
```

which tries to increment the variable `entries($item)` by 1 (the default increment amount of `incr`).

Spaces are important in tcl especially when calling functions/methods/procs as the language doesn't use commas to separate arguments, but spaces.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I need to understand better about Tcl